# Installing Subversion on top of already installed Apache?

Tags: windows, svn, apache

I have a working WAMP environment (Apache Friends). I decided to try Subversion and downloaded `CollabNetSubversion-server-1.6.9-1.win32.exe`. On the download page there were packages including Apache server which I did not use - because I didn't want to replace my current Apache installation.

I just installed the one that did not include Apache, and now I want to configure it to work with my current Apache. What should I do?

Is there an easy step by step tutorial to explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of tutorials such as the XAMPP (apache friends) version http://serk01.wordpress.com/2008/09/21/how-to-create-your-own-home-svn-repository-with-xamppapache/ and the WAMP version http://www.reloadedpc.com/other/setup-wamp-svn-subversion-windows/

If all you want to do is create a repository and do checkins and updates locally on your windows machine then just install TortoiseSVN. Tortoisesvn only installs the shell extension for windows explorer, not any command line svn executables. To get those you have to download them separately and make sure they're the same version of svn that tortoise uses or you'll get errors about version mismatches when using the command line svn.

Comment: Thank you rkulla for the tutorials. By the way what I actually want to do is to add svn support to Mantis. And from what it looks I'm in for hours of reading and trying.

Comment: Funny, the first tutorial instructs the user to copy `mod_authz_svn.so` and `mod_dav_svn.so` from Subversion to `xampp\apache\modules` directory ... but there are NO `*.so` files in subversion and no `bin` directory there!

Comment: Check C:\Program Files\Subversion\httpd\ Use your search tools. They should be somewhere.